# Jest hangs on code coverage after all spec files pass - React app

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Jest hangs after all spec files pass and displays "Running coverage on untested files..." forever

I have search all over the internet at this point and none of the suggestions seem to work.
I have tried excluding node_modules, package.json, and dist
My last resort is setting `collectCoverage: true,` to false and I can't do that.
Please help!

Comment: Have you looked at this thread? https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8310

Comment: Can you share your jest config? Jest might be collecting code coverage from your node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution:
In my jest.config.ts file I had `transform: { '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest' },`
so I changed that to `transform: { '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'babel-jest' },` and the code coverage works fine now.